# Can't find mistake in Angular + Spring Security app

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-security

I write a simple spring security project with angular client. 
  When I send data from login form in angular to java app, java returns to me message what I send null, but in angular, before sending I check it and it is not null.

Please help, I cant figure out whats going wrong=(

Log: 2019-07-15 15:30:12.127  WARN 8156 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.grokonez.jwtauthentication.controller.AuthRestAPIs.authenticateUser(com.grokonez.jwtauthentication.message.request.LoginForm), with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'loginForm' on field 'username': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.loginForm.username,NotBlank.username,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [loginForm.username,username]; arguments []; default message [username]]; default message [не может быть пусто]] ]

Java code:

```
  Model:

public class LoginForm {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=3, max = 60)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max = 40)
    private String password; ...

Controller:

@PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginForm loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getAuthorities()));
    }
```

Angular part:

Service:

```
   const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin';
  private registrationUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  signUp(registrationInfo: RegistrationInfo): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.registrationUrl, registrationInfo, httpOptions);
  }
  login(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Observable<JwtInfo> {
    console.log(loginInfo)
    return this.http.post<JwtInfo>(this.loginUrl, loginInfo, httpOptions);
  }
```

Component:

```
login(data) {
    this.loginInfo = new LoginInfo(data.userName, data.password);
    console.log(data.userName, data.password);
    this.authService.login(this.loginInfo).subscribe(
      (jwtResponse: JwtInfo) => {
        this.tokenStorage.saveToken(jwtResponse.accessToken);
        this.tokenStorage.saveUserName(jwtResponse.username);
        this.tokenStorage.saveAutorities(jwtResponse.authorities);

        this.username = this.tokenStorage.getUserName();
        this.authorities = this.tokenStorage.getAutorities();
        this.isLoggedIn = true;

        this.reloadPage();
      }, error => {
        this.warningMessage = error.error.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
      }
      );
  }
```

Log with problem: 2019-07-15 15:30:12.127 WARN 8156 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.grokonez.jwtauthentication.controller.AuthRestAPIs.authenticateUser(com.grokonez.jwtauthentication.message.request.LoginForm), with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'loginForm' on field 'username': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.loginForm.username,NotBlank.username,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [loginForm.username,username]; arguments []; default message [username]]; default message [не может быть пусто]] ]

Answer (score 0):

Its seems that LoginForm model with lowercase 'username' and you are sending 
console.log(data.userName, data.password);

userName - Case sensitive issue..
convert the angular login model to lowercase(username)

Comment: Why its still open ? Oleg - its better to closed this

Comment: Hi (oleg-pavlyukov) (@11437829 )  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.